# Can this sequence be done in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I certainly don't expect anyone to actually provide a working solution for this. My question at this point is a simple one: *can* this be done with an HTML5 canvas, or would I be spinning my wheels in the attempt?

I'm a programmer, but my forte is in PHP, JavaScript, traditional HTML, etc. ...I haven't had a chance to play with HTML5 yet.

The elements you see in the example, I can save out as individually as necessary. So to make the blocks rotate around the center, I was thinking I save a square image with the block in the appropriate corner, respectively. Then rotating the image would pivot around center appropriately, unless you can set a point of origin on an image a la PhotoShop.

The KineticJS library looks promising for this type of animation as well, but I'll leave the recommendations to you fine folks.

Anyway, here is the example I want to replicate:

[image]

Comment: It "can" be done using Canvas or SVG but it is a project in itself. The scope of this question is a little overly-broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks. And I understand it's broad; but like I said, I don't expect anyone to actually provide a solution. It seems like KineticJS could *do* everything you see there, which is essentially rotation and scale. The only question mark for me on feasibility is the timer in the center.

Comment: In general library recommendation questions are closed because they quickly become dated and are strongly opinionated. You may find better success in specific implementation questions one you have some code under your belt. Good luck. This sounds like a nifty little project.

Answer (score 6):

I won't give any library recommendations for the same reasons that @Diodeus points out, but maybe I can help your selection process. What you're trying to do can be done multiple ways in the browser right now: Canvas, SVG, and/or CSS3 animations.

Your example above is basically a few **vector** graphics composed together with a gradient on your center "pie timer". Because of this I would lean towards using S **V** G, especially if you want to allow interactions with your component (each SVG element can have event handlers).

The `canvas` element is better for "pixel by pixel" control of your visual content on the page. Adding content in the `canvas` doesn't grow the DOM (like with SVG) so it will normally perform better, but you lose things like native event handlers and animations that you will end up having to re-implement on your own.

[More about the choice between SVG and Canvas, and an SVG animation example](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/svg-or-canvas-choosing-between-the-two/)

Once you have the components in the page, they'll need to be wired up and animated. The animation can be broken down into:

1. Scaling
2. Background color fading
3. Rotation
4. "Weird gradient pie timer" [example with CSS3](http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/)

These can be done with CSS animations, SVG animations, or with plain old javascript. The choice depends on what you'll be animating. If I was selecting a library I would want to find one that tried to use the newer methods (SVG/CSS3) when it can, and gracefully degrade when it cannot.

I would be weary of libraries that try to re-implement things that are already available natively in the browser. Relying more on the browser instead of your own code to do things like animations means that the browser can optimize its operations and use things like hardware acceleration to improve your performance.

Hopefully this can aid your library selection. Remember, libraries come and go all the time so don't get too attached to one. An ideal implementation should allow for you to easily swap out your animation or display code without having to touch other unrelated pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up! Though, for the record, I don't think there's anything *weird* about my gradient pie timer. ;)

Comment: Haha true :) That's the best I could think of for a general term to describe that type of animation. Looks like a neat project! It'd be nice to see the implementation when you're done. Good luck

Comment: Is SVG still a viable option if the fan blades are images (and not natively drawn shapes or paths)? I'm new to SVG.

Comment: Yep -- you can use images alongside other SVG elements. The nice part about this is that all components will be in the same coordinate system and you can use the same transform/animation operations that you use on your non-image elements. (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement)

Comment: That would really be slick. And if my images are vector (they are, made in Illustrator) I can save them as .svg files and they'll scale like vectors in the browser, yes?

Comment: That's correct! Btw I just stumbled upon this article about exporting .svg for the web that you might find interesting: http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/09/exporting-svg-illustrator.html

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's not all that difficult when you break it down into pieces.

Here are some technologies and techniques to get you started.

You use Canvas by (1) displaying some drawings, (2) erasing, (3) displaying some new drawings

When you do this redrawing rapidly, you get animated effects like your image shows.

Html Canvas uses a `context` to draw with (think of it as the pen for the canvas)

- **drawing a path:** context.beginPath + context.moveTo + context.lineTo will define a path that creates your "fan blade" polygons. You can use context.fillStyle to fill the polygons with you colors.
- **fading:** context.globalAlpha will change the opacity of new drawings
- **rotating:** context.translate(centerX,centerY) + context.rotate(radianAngle) will rotate new drawings (like your rotating polygons, your tick-marks, )
- **scaling:** context.translate(centerX,centerY) + context.scale(scaleX,scaleY) will scale your polygons.
- **arcs:** context.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,beginningAngle,endingAngle) will draw an arc with a specified centerpoint and sweeping from a beginning angle to an ending angle.
- **math:** circleCircumferenceX = centerX+radius*Math.cos(radianAngle) circleCircumferenceY = centerY+radius*Math.sin(radianAngle) uses trigonometry to calculate an xy coordinate on the circumference of a circle.  You can combine this trig + Math.random to place your "speckles" in an arc around your centerpoint.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Actually, for the fan blade elements, tick marks, and circles inside and outside the blue ticker, I was thinking I could just use pre-made images (PNGs) and scale and rotate them appropriately, so I wouldn't have to draw new shapes. Thoughts?

Comment: The circles & ticks would scale/rotate easily. If your gif was created by scaling the blade image, then you could scale/rotate the blades too.  Visually, it looks like the shadow-connector part of the blades are scaling differently than the rectangle part of the blades--but I could be seeing it wrong.  The rectangle part of the blades could be a scale.  The shadow-connector part of the blades might need a simple path plus fill.

Comment: Actually, the rectangle and depth/shadow of the blade are one single image, so it scales the same. It's an optical illusion of depth because the shadow part terminates in an end point at the very center of the overall image, and I mad that the anchor point when I did the scaling, so it scales outward from the center of the image instead of the center of its own layer. So literally all you're seeing there is scaling of the top left blade, ticking of the center blue pie, some transparency, and obviously rotation of the blades.

Comment: Blade trickery!  Yep, then you could do the scaling/rotating with images.  Canvas rotates and scales around a fixed point--that's why there's a context.translate before rotating and scaling.

Comment: I wouldn't want to rotate the whole canvas, would I? Since not all elements rotate...

Comment: Correct--don't rotate every element on the canvas.  You can rotate just an element by (1) saving the unrotated context state (2) translate+rotate (3) draw an element you need rotated (4) restore the context to its unrotated state.  To save/restore the context you can use context.save() and context.restore().  Ironically translate and rotate work by translating(moving) and rotating the whole canvas--hence the need for context.save() and context.restore().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48383/discussion-between-praguian-and-marke)